# Setting TeamCity agent.work.dir from Custom Build

Tags: build, teamcity

I'm setting the **teamcity.build.checkoutDir** configuration parameter via the '**Run Custom Build**' dialog as I want to control the build location.

When looking at the '**Build Parameters**' page of the build, I can see the **teamcity.build.checkoutDir** parameter is correctly using my set value, but the '**Actual Parameters on Agent**' value always remains set to the default checkout path.

I've tried setting the **Version Control Settings**->**Checkout Directory** to **Custom Path** and the **teamcity.build.checkoutDir** parameter still does not use my custom setting.

Please can someone help me with this?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about a specifying a relative path to each agent's install dir?

Comment: I've tried both relative and absolute paths, but neither take affect. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I can't really help you here, since I've never needed to change the checkout directory. I do have the feeling that the teamcity.* properties are read-only, and more of an informational nature.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the value of teamcity.build.checkoutDir.  All the teamcity.build.* variables are read-only.

You can change the checkout directory by editing the VCS root settings.

1. Edit the build configuration
2. Select Version Control Settings
3. Next to Checkout Directory choose 'Custom Path' from the drop-down.

[image: Custom Checkout Directory]

You can also set a custom path by using custom client mappings for the VCS.

Comment: I set up custom path and enter that to nginx config for my functonal tests. Thanks!